# JavaEE CDI Injection - Cannot inject HttpServletRequest / Response

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, cdi

I have a web application that reads a query parameter. It uses the parameter to get some data from an outside-app-source. The web application is a simple Servlet:

```
@WebServlet(name = "SomethingServlet", urlPatterns = {"/"}, loadOnStartup = 0)
public class SomethingServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Inject
    InterfaceOfDesire objectOfDesire;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        objectOfDesire.doSomething();
    }
}
```

InterfaceOfDesire is an Interface which is (atm) implemented once. So there should be no ambiguities.

```
public interface InterfaceOfDesire {
    void doSomething();
}


public class ClassOfDesire implements InterfaceOfDesire {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        // do something very cool
    }
}
```

And last, but not least there is a resolver which resolves the kind of implemented class (atm only 1)

```
public class SomethingResolver {
    @Inject
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    @Inject
    private HttpServletResponse response;

    @Inject
    public SomethingResolver(ServletContext servletContext) {
        // do something with the servlet context
    }

    @Produces
    public InterfaceOfDesire getInstance() {
        // do something with request and response
        // afterwards return object
        return new ClassOfDesire();
    }
}
```

Now I get the error

```
WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type HttpServletResponse with qualifiers @Default
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you marked your classes where you are using `@Inject` with `@Named` + scope annotation (`@ApplicationScoped`, etc...) Don't forget `ViewScoped` and `SessionScoped` need to implements `Serializable`.

Comment: what container are you deploying to? Include the version.

Answer (score -1):

I would say the bean (`SomethingResolver`) needs to be somehow bound to the HTTP request or to its session. Only then it can get access to `HttpServletRequest` (or response).

Try annotating it with either `@RequestScoped`. `@SessionScoped` might work as well.

The reason behind this is that the way you have it now, the bean lifecycle is not bound to the request - it can be even longer than the request. CDI has no way of telling which servlet request should then be injected into it.